# Horizontal align thumbnails to center in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have 3 thumbnails horizontally beside one another and centred. The issue with these is that they are not centred. I'm also wondering whether I could simplify the code since for example `<div class="column">` is repetitive in all 3 parts. However, when I try to do that, the pictures stack vertically instead of horizontally and I'm not sure why. So my questions are:

1. How do I centre the 3 pictures on the page?
2. How do I simplify the code without the images becoming vertically stacked?

**Current code**

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://www.microsoft.com/global/en-us/news/PublishingImages/bod/billg/gates_print.jpg" alt="My Image" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Lalalala</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://www.microsoft.com/global/en-us/news/PublishingImages/bod/billg/gates_print.jpg" alt="My Image" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Lalalala</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://www.microsoft.com/global/en-us/news/PublishingImages/bod/billg/gates_print.jpg" alt="My Image" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Lalalala</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is standard Bootstrap 3. By changing "row" to "column" in the first divs, the pictures stacked vertically but I'm not sure if that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sure if I understood your question correctly but gave it a shot anyway. Is this what you wanted?

I removed all `<div class="column">` and replaced with single `<div class="row">`

I also set col size to `col-xs-4` for each thumbnail.

**Have a look at this link for an example using your code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/p9k3x/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly you need to:

1. Add a `<div class="container">` and `<div class="row">` tags to your
   code.
2. Remove the `<div class="column">` tags
3. Change your `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">` to `<div class="col-xs-4>`

The `container` class centers the elements inside that div on the page. You want all of your `col-xx-##` classes nested inside of a `<div class="row">`. Also, Bootstrap 3 is "Mobile First" so anything done in the `col-xs-##` class groupings will be inherited by the larger screen resolutions. The reason for using `col-xs-4` class is because you want 3 total columns, so you want to take up 4 of the 12 column spaces. It is a little counter intuitive. [Here is some Bootstrap 3 documentation on the grid system.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

I hope this answers your question! Happy coding.

Once you make those changes your code should look like this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://www.microsoft.com/global/en-us/news/PublishingImages/bod/billg/gates_print.jpg" alt="My Image" />
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>Lalalala</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://www.microsoft.com/global/en-us/news/PublishingImages/bod/billg/gates_print.jpg" alt="My Image" />
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>Lalalala</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://www.microsoft.com/global/en-us/news/PublishingImages/bod/billg/gates_print.jpg" alt="My Image" />
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>Lalalala</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Row Div --> 


</div><!-- End Container Div -->
```